# Question on Law of Large numbers argument including conditioning

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider a random process $X_n$ that may be non i.i.d. Assume that for $X_n$ the following equality holds 
\begin{equation}
\sup_{\ell \geq 1}\text{ess} \sup \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i= (\ell -1)n +1}^{\ell n} X_i <\alpha \bigg|\ X_1,\dots,X_{(\ell-1)n}\right) =0.
\end{equation}
I am trying to investigate under which conditions the following equation holds:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{\ell \geq 1}\text{ess} \sup \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i= (\ell -1)n +1}^{\ell n} X_i <\alpha \bigg|\ X_1,\dots,X_{(\ell-1)n}\right) =0.
\end{equation}
When the limit is outside then the $\ell$ that attains the supremum depends on $n$ and I am not sure if the result holds or how to rigorously show it. Could someone intuitively explain what is the core difference between those two equations and what assumptions might be needed to proceed to prove the second equation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have $\alpha$ *and* $\epsilon$? I'm confused

Comment: Aso, what is ess sup being applied to?

Comment: Yes you are right. Having one of $\epsilon$ or $\alpha$ is enough.

Comment: The ess $\sup$ is applied to the conditioning. Inuitively  it indicates that we condition to an event such that the probability is maximized. Does this make sense?

Comment: I see, thanks. (Also you still have $\epsilon$ in the question statement, which might confuse others)

Comment: Fixed. An extra assumption that I am considering for this problem is to assume that the random variables are discrete and can take values in a finite set. This way the $\text{ess} \sup$ should become a $max$.

Comment: The first condition just means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i= (\ell -1)n +1}^{\ell n} X_i <\alpha \bigg|\ X_1,\dots,X_{(\ell-1)n}\right) =0$ a.s. for all $\ell\ge 1$.